# Can't write to raid on Fedora

Tags: linux, raid, fedora, raid-1

I just did a fresh install of Fedora 11 and added Raid 1 following this tutorial: http://www.optimiz3.com/installing-fedora-11-and-setting-up-a-raid-0-1-5-6-or-10-array/

Now I see the filesystem when I open 'Computer' in the GUI, and I open it and see 'lost+found', but i can't write to the drive. The option is simply greyed out. And when I view Properties on the drive and go to Permissions, it says 'The permissions of {driveid} could not be determined.'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you can write files as root your RAID is probably working just fine. The issue would be that your user account does not have permission to write to the mount point where you mounted your RAID. To solve this you can create a directory for yourself as root and change the owner to your user account or you can change the permissions on the mount point. For large chunks of space where I tend to dump stuff I usually set permissions like /tmp (chmod 1777 /mountpoint) and leave the mount point owned as root.